# Trying to add a Java Exception that will catch anything else other than "yes" or "no", if it does, loop back until they get it

Tags: string, loops, exception

I am wanting to practice how I can stop the user to enter anything else other that a YES or NO and if so to loop back to the original instruction until the user will enter the correct data to continue. I wanted to see if this could be done with String, hopefully there is some good advice I could receive.

The code below is part of my original code, I did not want to paste the entire thing in here. This should be enough to get my point across what I'm trying to do, I'm new to programming and I want to learn.

```
    type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(UserName + ", Can You Multiply Both Your Numbers ?");

    //Here is where I got stuck....
    if (type.equals("Yes") || type.equals("yes")) {
        StringResultFromUserOne = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is Your Awnser ?");
        ResultFromUserOne = Integer.parseInt(StringResultFromUserOne);

        if (ResultFromUserOne == AnswerForMult) {
            System.out.println(ResultFromUserOne + " Is Correct.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(ResultFromUserOne + " Is Wrong, The Correct Answer Is: " + AnswerForMult);
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("The Answer Is: " + AnswerForMult);
    }
```

Comment: You don't need an Exception to achieve what you want.  Just use a loop that keeps reading inputs until it finds a "yes" or "no".

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do (I don't think I understand you correctly, please explain again if this isn't correct):

```
String type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(UserName + ", Can You Multiply Both Your Numbers ?");

if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    // code if answer is yes.
} else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
    // code if answer is no.
} else {
    // code if answer isn't no or yes.
}
```

This is a simple code which checks what the input is and executes code depending on the answer.